# Proving Lebesgue integration result

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

I have a Lebesgue integration question and a proposed proof. Please advise.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$(denote the boundary as $\partial \Omega$) and consider $$\int_{\partial \Omega} vf d\lambda \geq 0 \text{  } \text{ for all } v \in C^{1}(\overline{\Omega}) \text{  } \text{  with } f \in C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$$
then  it follows that $f \geq 0$ for every $x \in \partial \Omega$. Also we are given that $v|_{\partial \Omega} \geq 0$.

Comment: Aren't you trying to prove that $f \geq 0$ on $\Omega$, not $\partial \Omega$? Translating information from $\partial \Omega$ to $\Omega$ will require some kind of integration by parts.

Comment: @Ian No sorry I forgot to state that I want $f \geq 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Will edit now.

Comment: In that case I'm pretty sure you're fine. The following is probably closer to what was expected, since it generalizes better. We have $\langle v,f \rangle \geq 0$ for all $v$. Suppose there were $v$ with $\langle v,f \rangle > 0$, then $\langle -v,f \rangle < 0$, which is a contradiction. We conclude $\langle v,f \rangle = 0$ for all $v$, which since $f \in C^1$ means $f=0$.

Comment: I just realized that you were not fine, because $v=-f$ when $f<0$ and $0$ otherwise is not necessarily $C^1$. It's $C^0$, but not $C^1$. You need to approximate such a function by $C^1$ functions.

Comment: @Ian Approximate what function by $C^{1}$ functions? What $v$ would you suggest I choose?

Comment: You can't use your $v$, because it is only $C^0$ in general, not $C^1$. (If $f'$ is not $0$ when $f$ changes sign, then your $v$ will not be differentiable there.) To fix this, try to justify that there is a $w \in C^1$ with $\| w - v \|_{L^2} < \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon$ you pick. Then by Cauchy-Schwarz you have $|\langle w,f \rangle - \langle v,f \rangle| \leq \| w - v \|_{L^2} \| f \|_{L^2} \leq \varepsilon \| f \|_{L^2}$. So if $\langle v,f \rangle$ were negative, you would be able to choose $\varepsilon$ small enough that $\langle w,f \rangle$ would be negative too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining my ideas into an answer:

Define $v(x) = -f(x) \chi_{f^{-1}(-\infty,0]}(x)$. Note that in general $v$ is only $C^0$, not $C^1$, so we cannot simply use it as a test function directly.

Suppose there exists $x$ so that $f(x) < 0$. Then by continuity of $v$ and $f$, $\langle v,f \rangle < 0$. By Cauchy-Schwarz we have that $\| f \|_{L^2} > 0$, so we can define $\varepsilon = \frac{|\langle v,f \rangle|}{2 \| f \|_{L^2}}$. Find $w \in C^1$ so that $\| w - v \|_{L^2} < \varepsilon$. (It takes a little work to show this can be done.) Then, using Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$\left | \langle w,f \rangle - \langle v,f \rangle \right | = \left | \langle w-v,f \rangle \right | \leq \| w - v \|_{L^2} \| f \|_{L^2} \leq \frac{|\langle v,f \rangle| \| f \|_{L^2}}{2 \| f \|_{L^2}} = \frac{|\langle v,f \rangle|}{2}.$$

Consequently

$$\langle w,f \rangle \leq \frac{\langle v,f \rangle}{2} < 0$$

which achieves the desired contradiction.

Comment: Firstly, for your last step I get that $|\langle w,f \rangle - \langle v, r \rangle| \leq \frac{\langle v,f \rangle}{2}$ implies that $\langle w,f \rangle \geq \frac{\langle v,f \rangle}{2}$. Also are you assuming that $\Omega$ is bounded, is that why you are taking $v,f \in L^{2}$?

Comment: There were a few typos. Anyway, $|\langle w,f \rangle - \langle v,f \rangle| \leq \frac{|\langle v,f \rangle|}{2}$ implies that $\frac{3 \langle v,f \rangle}{2} \leq \langle w,f \rangle \leq \frac{ \langle v,f \rangle}{2}$. I do not need to assume that $\Omega$ is bounded; $\Omega$ really has nothing to do with the problem. I am however assuming that $\partial \Omega$ has finite induced measure.

Comment: Does $\partial \Omega$ having finite measure not imply that it is bounded? I thought you were assuming $\partial \Omega$ is closed and bounded(compact) therefore $f \in C^{1}$ implies that $f \in L^{2}$.

Comment: I am not sure whether the fact that $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of a set implies that it must be bounded to have finite induced measure. I haven't studied subjects like PDE where boundaries come up very much. One thing I can say is that $\partial \Omega$ is *always* closed.

Comment: @LucioD Anyway, if $\partial \Omega$ doesn't have finite measure, it *does* have $\sigma$-finite measure, so you can do this argument countably many times on finite measure sets whose union is $\partial \Omega$, then conclude the result for all of $\partial \Omega$. (This is a standard trick in measure theory.)

Comment: Also, this may clear some things up: $\langle w,f \rangle = \langle v,f \rangle + \langle w-v,f \rangle \leq \langle v,f \rangle + |\langle w-v,f \rangle| \leq \langle v,f \rangle + |\langle v,f \rangle|/2 = \langle v,f \rangle - \langle v,f \rangle/2 = \langle v,f \rangle/2$. In the second to last step, when we remove the absolute values, we pick up a minus sign, because $\langle v,f \rangle < 0$.

Comment: Yes but is there a result that states that if $f \in C^{1}(\partial\Omega)$ and $\partial \Omega$ is $\sigma$-finite then it follows that $f \in L^{2}(\partial \Omega)$, since that is what you are using. I know this is true for $\partial \Omega$ compact. The fact that $\partial \Omega$ is $\sigma$- finite doesn't imply that it is bounded(Example $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$). What do you think?

Comment: You do not need $\partial \Omega$ to have finite measure. Let $\partial \Omega = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ where each $A_k$ has finite induced measure. Apply the preceding argument to the restriction of $f$ to $A_k$ and you get that $f \geq 0$ on $A_k$. Since any $x \in \partial \Omega$ is in some $A_k$, $f \geq 0$ on all of $\partial \Omega$. You can justify the argument that the restriction of $f$ to $A_k$ is $L^2$ by approximating from the inside by compact sets. (It is easier to show that $C^1$ functions are absolutely continuous and then use Radon-Nikodym, however.)

Comment: Er, disregard that remark about Radon-Nikodym, it's not as easy as I thought. Also, I should mention that you *do not* need $f \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$.

Comment: Sorry if this is too much questions, just out of interest. What do you mean by 'finite induced measure'? Also, would you show that $w \in C^{1}$ implies that $\Vert w-v \Vert_{L^{2}} < \epsilon$ by referring to a density result of $L^{p}$ spaces as a start?

Comment: The measure with respect to which you are integrating on $\partial \Omega$ is not the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure, it is a measure induced by the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure. (If it were the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure, the integral of anything on the boundary of a sphere would be $0$.) And you have it backwards: for every $v \in L^2$ there exists such a $w \in C^1$. This is a standard density result but I do not have a name for it.

Comment: Okay thanks for the assistance. Do you maybe have a book you could recommend or a set of online notes where I could read up on the concepts of induced measures and so on?

Comment: I think if you want heavy details on induced measures in particular, you would want to read either a text on PDE or a text on Riemannian geometry. I've studied neither, so I'm not much help there. For an analysis text, my current favorite is Royden/Fitzpatrick.

Comment: One last thing, are we guaranteed to find $w \in C^{1}$ such that $w \geq 0$ on $\partial \Omega$? That was also a requirement.

Comment: I think you can get $w \geq v$, from which $w \geq 0$ follows. (The above does not prove this, however.)

Comment: Hmm...if you can't get $w \geq v$ by some standard result then you can force $w \geq 0$ by taking $w$ to be the convolution of $v$ with a smooth approximate identity.

Comment: Then would $w \in C^{\infty}(\partial \Omega) \subset C^{1}(\partial \Omega)$?

Comment: Yes; if $f$ is $C^n$ and $g$ is $C^m$ then $f * g$ is $C^{\max \{ m,n \}}$.

Comment: Why would $w \geq 0$ follow from a convolution?

Comment: Look at the definition: if $f,g \geq 0$, then for each $x$, $(f*g)(x)$ is an integral of a product of two nonnegative functions.

Comment: The mollification is usually formulated for an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. $\partial \Omega$ is closed and does not necessarily have any interior points. Can you mollify a function over any subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: The extension to an open neighborhood will be as smooth as you want.

Comment: So are you saying that the mollification can be applied to a function defined on any subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$(regardless of whether it is open)? Do you know why then in Lawrence Evans book 'Partial Differential Equations' pg629, they define the mollification specifically for open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: To my understanding, yes, essentially because the procedure furnishes an extension to an open set. (Note that this extension may be trivial if you started with a set of measure zero.)

Comment: I'm not really following your reason 'furnishes an extension to an open set', why does that allow mollification on any subset?

Answer (score 0):

**Proof**:
Assume that $f(x) \ngeq 0$ for every $x \in \partial \Omega$.

If we define $v(x) := \begin{cases}  &~~ 0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{ if } f(x) \geq 0\\ &-f(x) ~~~~~~~~~~~\text{ if } f(x) < 0   \end{cases}$

then it follows that $v(x) \geq 0$ and $v(x)f(x) \leq 0$ for every $x \in \partial \Omega$, it can then easily be shown that $\int_{\partial \Omega}vf d\lambda \leq 0$. This implies that $\int_{\Omega}vf d\lambda = 0$(since we assume that $\int_{\partial \Omega}vf d \lambda \geq 0$) which implies $vf = 0$ for every $x \in \partial \Omega$ with $v$ defined as above. Consider a point $x \in \partial \Omega$ such that $f(x) < 0$ then $v = -f(x)$. Therefore, $v(x)f(x) = - f^{2}(x) < 0$, but $v(x)f(x) = 0$. Contradiction. Therefore $f(x) \geq 0$ for every $x \in \partial \Omega$. 
$\square$

Is the reasoning fine here? Is there a better way to prove this? Thanks.